# pandas convert columns to percentages of the totals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 4 columns an ID and three categories that results fell into

```
  <80% 80-90 >90
id
1   2     4    4
2   3     6    1
3   7     0    3
```

I would like to convert it to percentages ie:

```
   <80% 80-90 >90
id
1   20%   40%  40%
2   30%   60%  10%
3   70%    0%  30%
```

this seems like it should be within pandas capabilities but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide an example dataframe, your numbers are a bit hard to interpret at first glace.

Comment: I'm not sure how to post the dataframe and I appologize my example lost its format but I have an index of ID and colums for <80%, 80%-90% and >90%. then I have data in the rows so row 0 may be iindex 1 with  [3, 4,3] . I would like row 0 index 1 to have 30%, 40%, 30%. I am very new to pandas sorry i am still explaining it poorly.

Comment: I guess it actually looks more like this:
results <80%, 80%-90%, >90%
id
1           3          4                 3
2           7           3                0

and I want:
results <80%, 80%-90%, >90%
id
1           30%      40%          30%
2           70%      30%          0%

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this using basic pandas operators `.div` and `.sum`, using the `axis` argument to make sure the calculations happen the way you want:

```
cols = ['<80%', '80-90', '>90']
df[cols] = df[cols].div(df[cols].sum(axis=1), axis=0).multiply(100)
```

- Calculate the sum of each column (`df[cols].sum(axis=1`).  `axis=1` makes the summation occur across the rows, rather than down the columns.
- Divide the dataframe by the resulting series (`df[cols].div(df[cols].sum(axis=1), axis=0`).  `axis=0` makes the division happen across the columns.
- To finish, multiply the results by `100` so they are percentages between 0 and 100 instead of proportions between 0 and 1 (or you can skip this step and store them as proportions).

Comment: Thank you so much this did the trick. Thanks for explaining the portions as well. Pandas seems to be a great tool that hopefully I'll get better at soon.

Comment: "Proportions" are percentages. `0.1` IS `10%`. The `%` is basically a "divide by 100" operator. Putting `100` there is wrong and will probably lead to all kinds of errors down the line.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa I'm not sure I follow.  I understand that you can express the same value as 0.1 or as 10%, but the OP asked for the latter.  Whether or not that leads to problems down the line depends on the OP's use case - maybe it needs to be in % format for some reason.

Comment: OK, maybe "wrong" is not the correct word here. Your solution certainly is correct. I should probably say it is a dangerous paradigm. You cannot store `10%` in a DataFrame/array, but you can store `0.1`.

Answer (score 6):

```
df/df.sum()
```

If you want to divide the sum of rows, transpose it first.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `.apply()` method:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x/sum(x)*100, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim Tian's answer pretty much worked for me, but maybe this helps if you have a df with several columns and want to do a % column wise.

```html
df_pct = df/df[df.columns].sum()*100
```

I was having trouble because I wanted to have the result of a pd.pivot_table expressed as a %, but couldn't get it to work. So I just used that code on the resulting table itself and it worked.

Comment: This doesn't get the correct answer. The first row of `df_pct` is [16.666667, 40.0, 50.0], not [20, 20, 40].

Comment: @jjramsey you are right, OP asked for row calculations and mine was column wise. You can transpose and solve it.
`x = x.transpose()`, then `x = x/x[x.columns].sum()*100` and `x = x.transpose()`
That does it. I don't know if it's the best way to do it.