# How to Perform operation in each columns in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I have this dataset and I want to check the percentage of each cell per year. Such as dividing each value by the sum of values of that year ( value/sum(1960) )*100. How can I get the value for each column and each row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42006346/2714651?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the equivalent of `5 / sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) * 100`. If that's the case, then you could do the following:

```py
subset_cols = df.columns

perc_df = df[subset_cols] / df[subset_cols].sum(axis=0) * 100
```

Using `axis=0` will apply the function to each column, whereas `axis=1` will apply to each row.

Answer (score 0):

To convert column values into percentages, this is the simplest way:

```
df['1960_percentages'] = 100*df.1960/df.1960.sum()
```

Repeat similarly for other columns.

Note: This creates a new column in your dataframe keeping the original data intact. If you would just like to replace, do the following:

```
df.1960 /= (df.1960.sum() / 100)
```

Edit: To do the same for multiple columns at once:

```
cols = # list of columns to apply this over (set to df.columns for all columns)
df[cols] /= (df[cols].sum(axis=0) / 100)
```

Comment: I have total 60 columns so it's very difficult to write for all columns. How can I run a loop for this?

Comment: @RavikantPandey Check my edit! You can also do this more naively by just creating that list of columns and then doing the same thing as for first column in a for loop.