# Creating Stack Graph

Tags: graph, stacked

I would like to create a stack bar graph to see the percentage of each virus by week using seaborn.
Below is my dataset:

````
``` 
data = {'Week': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'Virus': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B']}
      
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```
````

Every bar should represent one week of data with each virus having a colour of its own and the % on the stacked bar graph itself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn itself doesn't provide easy stacked chart creation. Using pandas bar plot and selecting `stacked=True` makes it pretty easy.
Below is the code. The data is changed to allow for easy plotting, so that the weeks are in index and each column has the virus names.

```
data = {'Week': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'Virus': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df=df.groupby(['Virus', 'Week']).size().reset_index().pivot(columns='Virus', index='Week', values=0)
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

As requested in comments have been incorporated.

- To change the values to percentage, you can use `div` (borrowed code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006346/pandas-convert-columns-to-percentages-of-the-totals))
- Use `bbox_to_anchor()` to set the position of the legend
- Use `rot()` to keep the x-axis labels vertical

```
data = {'Week': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        'Virus': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df.groupby(['Virus', 'Week']).size().reset_index().pivot(columns='Virus', index='Week', values=0)
cols=df.columns.values
df[cols]=df[cols].div(df[cols].sum(axis=1), axis=0).multiply(100)

fig = plt.figure()
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot = 0, ax=fig.gca())
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: Hi Redox. Thank you for your answer. I need the stacked graph to be 100%. That is all the graph should be the same height

Comment: Yes. Each graph is the same height. Sorry to trouble you as my original list of virus is much longer, is it possible to have the menu on the side?

Comment: Menu? You mean Legend? You want it outside the box?

Comment: Legend to be separately on the side.